# How can I change the default search paths in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc

We have one build machine which has some static libraries at unusual paths, and gcc doesn't find them when via the `-l` option, all other build machines run fine. But it seems this one configured incorrectly or something.

The solutions we have tried:

- Check the host name of the build machine in build script and add the `-L` command line option if it matches name the problematic build machine (very ugly).
- Print the list of search dirs using the `-print-search-dirs` option
  and symlink the problematic library into the first one (too hackish).

What I would like to do is simply add an extra path to search paths system wide to the gcc.

Is there a way to change/configure the **default** library search paths in GCC? Is there a config file where the list of the defaults are stored?

Comment: `-L /path/to/library -llibrary` should do it.

Comment: @sjsam that won't be adequate i'm sorry.

Comment: setting the `LIBRARY_PATH` did not help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
-l:<PATH_TO_YOUR_LIBRARY>
```

Or you can set up the `/etc/ld.so.conf` with the path to your directory of which you have the shared library installed. You might have to run `ldconfig` after that.

Comment: We have linking problem against static libs. It looks like /etc/ld.so.conf deals with the loader isn't it?